svnadmin hotcopy incremental size is growing indefinitely
I am using svnadmin hotcopy --incremental to create daily backups of a subversion repository. The size of the hotcopy initially was approximately the same size as the repository (which I would expect). However, with each increment, the size grows by more or less 10% of the original size. Fortunately this is a virtual machine so that I can expand the destination disk, but I'd much rather find out what I'm doing wrong.
The hotcopy runs unattended, but I'm crating logs from which I can say that the hotcopy only processes only new revisions (so it is not the same problem as in Does svn hotcopy overwrite existing files?). The repo uses the FSFS file system. It is currently 109 GB large, and today the hotcopy has exceeded 200 GB.
The svn server is TortoiseSVN 1.12.28653, running under MS Windows Server 2019. These are not the latest versions, and if this is a known problem that was fixed in a more recent version, I will recommend to upgrade.
Thank you for any hints!


TortoiseSVN is a client program, not a server. 2. You should show the exact commands you or your script is running. 3. You can look into the repository’s directory and the directory of the “hotcopy” and check what’s different to get some clues.


Re "1. TortoiseSVN is a client program, not a server." - I would have thought so too, but it comes with svnserve.exe which is a full-blown svn server. (I'll answer to 2. and 3. after the weekend.)

@bahrep The exact command line is svnadmin --incremental "<repo-path>" "<hotcopy-path>".  is the base path of the reporitory, i.e. the folder that contains the folders conf, db, hooks, etc.  is the same (existing) path on each invocation.
Regarding differences between repo and hotcopy: More than 100 files exist in the hotcopy which do not exist in the repo, totalling to 125 GB. File names are like _1h41.cfs or _1h5f_1.del, in addition to 16 files with names like segments_18yi which make 2.4 kB. The repo's index folder contains only 19 files with 9 GB in total.

Correction to my previous comment: The command line is svnadmin hotcopy --incremental "<repo-path>" "<hotcopy-path>".

Problem solved. We have a 3rd party add-on which creates indexing information and stores it in temporary files in the "index" subfolder of the repository. svnadmin hotcopy obviously just copies the directory tree with everything in it, and thus also copies the "index" folder although not part of the repository. As a solution, I'm trying to move the temporary "index" folder to a different location (and if that doesn't work, I'm going to delete it from the hotcopy).
